# How are webstreams treated by the client

Tags: javascript, stream

I am playing with the [MDN example for streams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams), with some modifications. This is how I believe it works (and would be useful for):

1. You may request a large file
2. The file actually arrives in the browser in chunks of bytes

   2.b The chunk is then enqueued
3. You can access those bytes (the chunk) as it lands as opposed to wait the whole process
4. And start analyzing the data

This chunks are enqueued as they arrive.

Instead of creating a ReadableStream (first MDN example) the chunks are just read as they land on the client and the bytes are decoded decode:

```js
async function streamData() {
  const response = await fetch("long.txt");
  // reader helps to read the data as it arrives to the client
  const reader = await response.body?.getReader();
  const decoder = new TextDecoder();
  if (reader !== undefined) await chunkToText(reader, decoder);
}

async function chunkToText(reader, decoder) {
  const chunk = await reader.read();
  if (chunk.done) return
  const newValue = decoder.decode(chunk.value);
  console.log("parsed chunk!", newValue);
  await chunkToText(reader, decoder);
}
```

Question:

1. Can you spot any conceptual mistake in the understanding of this process?
2. How is it possible that the chunks are always such that they can be decoded to UTF-8 ? Couldn't it occur that the chunk bytes are such that the decoder errors because of a missing piece of the utf8 code?